# AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) is live. Now how do we check it on live environment?

Tags: mobile, amp-html

We recently made the AMP pages for our website. How do I test on live environment?

I have already tested from https://validator.ampproject.org/ and https://search.google.com/test/amp

I just wanted to check in real. Is it possible?

Comment: share URL to your project, how come some one tell you this without taking a look on your project.

Comment: Please share URL to your page/pages? Have you looked at this link? https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/amp-your-content-preview-of-amped.html